# Trying to understand foreign key syntax

Tags: sql, sqlite

Just starting out with SQL.  I understand the idea of foreign keys just fine, but I'm trying to learn the syntax of how to implement them and reading the [sqlite page](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) just gives me more questions than answers.  Is there any difference in the following two lines?

```
CREATE TABLE child(x REFERENCES parent(id));
CREATE TABLE child(FOREIGN KEY x REFERENCES parent(id));
```

Also, from my understanding, columns are specified by the "table.column" format, so I'd want to type "parent.id" above, but it seems all the reading I've done says "parent(id)".  What's the difference between the two and why use parent.id sometimes and parent(id) others?

Are we not supposed to bind any kind of affinity (I think I'm using the terminology correctly) to the foreign keys because it should just use whatever the parent key uses?

I have more questions, but this is a good start.  Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2):

The difference between:

```
CREATE TABLE child(x REFERENCES parent(id));
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE child(FOREIGN KEY x REFERENCES parent(id));
```

is that the first creates a table with one column named `x` and a foreign key constraint.  The second creates a table without any columns but only a foreign key constraint.  The second statement should fail, since it references an unknown column `x`.

You have to declare a foreign key separately if it consists of multiple columns.  For one column,

```
column1 references parent(column1)
```

works fine.  For multiple columns, you need:

```
column1, column2, foreign key (column1, column2) references parent(column1, column2)
```

This also explains why the `table.column` format does not suffice.  It does not provide a way to specify multiple columns.

Comment: That helps a little, what if I rewrote the second line as "CREATE TABLE child(x, FOREIGN KEY x REFERENCES parent(id));"?  How would that be different than the line without mentioning FOREIGN KEY?

Comment: @DanGoodspeed It would not be different at all.